# Joomla: How to set the default template?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I would like to change the template in a Joomla website but when I install it I can't select it as default theme, for example like I could do in WordPress.

How can I activate the template?

I attach the screenshot of the backend:

[screensoht of the backend http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/2283/schermata20110228a17540.png](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/2283/schermata20110228a17540.png)

Thanks

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow. Please see the help pages on what StackOverflow is, wants to be, what belongs here and what not.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Top Menu bar => Extensions => Template Manager.

Here select the template(from left side radio button) which you want to make default.

And click on the default(star) icon, on top-right side.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The problem was that I wasn't a super  administrator but only an administrator so I hadn't the right to set the default template.